# Activity launched from a service loses the "extra" from the bundle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-bundle

Calling code (run in service):

```
Intent textIntent = new Intent(this, TextActivity.class);
textIntent.putExtra("text_seq", message.xfer.seq);
textIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(textIntent);
```

Called code (in `TextActivity`):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    Log.d(TAG, "" + bundle.getInt("text_seq"))
    ...
```

In fact the whole bundle is lost - the code above throws an NPE when calling `bundle.getInt()`.

I'm sure there's something obvious I have missed...

Comment: use `Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtra();` and not the one in the onCreate args

Comment: I never used the bundle-arg from onCreate, but there is as far as I know there is the getIntent().getExtra(); method to get the bundle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundle you are reading is NOT for that purpose. As [per docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))

```
void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

> Bundle: If the activity is being re-initialized after previously being
>   shut down then this Bundle contains the data it most recently supplied
>   in onSaveInstanceState(Bundle). Note: Otherwise it is null.

If you need to get extras you need to call:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtra();
```

and then you can try to get your values:

```
int myVal = extras.getInt(key);
```

Alternatively you can try to use:

```
int myVal = getIntent().getIntExtra(key, defaultVal);
```

Comment: Thanks, I had wrongly assumed that the bundle given to `onCreate` was the bundle I sent with the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `getIntent().getInt("text_seq")` ?

Comment: You mean `getIntent().getExtra().getInt("text_seq");`, right?

Answer (score 0):

get your bundle like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
   Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtra();
    Log.d(TAG, "" + intentBundle.getExtra(“text_seq"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bundle you're using is the `savedInstanceState` you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846817/when-is-the-savedinstancestate-bundle-actually-used).

What you need to use is this:

```
Bundle intentBundle = getIntent().getExtra();
```

Since you added the bundle to `Intent` extras, so you need to get it from the `getIntent().getExtra()`

also you can get individual items like this :

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("text_seq", defaultValToReturn);
```